# Unity models in openGLES iOS

Tags: ios, animation, opengl-es, unity-game-engine

How we can load unity animated models in openGLES and animated then in opengles ? 
Is there any example code or tutorial available ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this answer @[Answers.Unity](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/21010/binding-texture-directly-to-opengles-with-unity-ip.html), Kindly visit it. It might help you.